# Azure Logic Apps 302 Error MVC Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to create my very first Azure Logic App that simply makes a http post request every hour to a website that has MVC ASP authentication. Whilst setting up the http Logic App action I am using the Basic option to enter the user details.

When it is run, the Logic App keeps failing and returning a 302 (redirect) error; I guess this is because the http post is getting redirected to the account login page.

I have run a test by carrying out a Logic App action to run a http post on a url from the same site that doesn't require user authorisation and it works.

I have also read that I may be able to add configuration to the Logic App action using the Run After rules, but for some reason this option is disabled for my action.

I'd appreciate it if someone with any knowledge in this area, could provide some possible direction.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to do request with Postman? Is it same with Logic Apps?

Comment: Have you resolved the issue?